# How do I access an open API like Ethereum with a spreadsheet like excel or sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, api

Is there a way to access the Ethereum API using either excel or sheets or some other database with a website front end?  I'm trying to track my transactions.

Comment: Can excel accept API data? I guess I shouldn;t be surprised if it did, but I'm wondering if there is a reason you would think that it could. is there are particular feature you've seen that makes you think this is possible?

Comment: The “Get External Data” → “From Other Sources” menu (in Excel) suggests that it has some such capability.

Comment: @FrankThomas when I worked on trading desk years ago, they had custom functions that pulled in data. Don’t know if they were web APIs or not.

Comment: What data do you want to see in Excel? Prices?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio prices, balances, transactions...etc. want to track my positions and other data.

Comment: Maybe this might help you https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104381695?tab=overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets has a scripts editor where you an access APIs.  https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-3#9

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/